# Android programmatically release wake_lock

Tags: android

I'm using this method to wake lock my application. How can I release it automatically?

```
    PowerManager mgr = (PowerManager)G.context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    PowerManager.WakeLock wakeLock = mgr.newWakeLock(
            PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "TmyWakeLock"
    );
```

Comment: You shouldn't be holding a wake lock permanently until on destroy(). That's going to kill the battery. Get the wake lock, so the work, then release it again until needed. Even better, use a WakefulIntentService.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You call `wakeLock.release()`, possibly in the `onDestroy()` method.

Comment: thanks. after `super.onDestroy ();` or before `super.onDestroy ();` whats influence?

Comment: It probably doesn't matter, but try it both ways.

Answer (score 0):

Or You can create a new Alarm using [Alarm Manager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) and release the wake lock inside it, at whatever time you want.